# Finding multiple regex (stored infile) line by line in text (stored in another file)

Tags: python

I'm looking for an efficient script that will search for 'n' regex patterns (stored in "find_these.txt") in 'm' lines (stored in "text.txt") and list all instances of regex pattern finds.

File `"text.txt"` contains a corpus

File `"find_these.txt"` contains regex patters to search for

File `"output.txt"` to contain all matches (of all regex patterns in every line of corpus)

Psudocode as follows:

```
outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
for pattern in "find_these.txt"
    for line in "text.txt"
        if found then write "pattern ---> line" into outputFile
close all files
```

It'd be really helpful if I can write line number along with line as well.  as in:

```
outputFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
for pattern in "find_these.txt"
    for line in "text.txt"
        if found then write "pattern ---> lineNumber ---> line" into outputFile
close all files
```

Can somebody help me please?  Or point me to an exising solution somewhere?  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you want to store entire line in output file or just the matched string?

Comment: Entire string (line from the text.txt file) please.

Comment: Is it possible to find what column (position of the regex match) in a line as well.

Comment: Also, I'd like multiple finds in each sentence.  E.g.: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] pattern should be flagged twice in "Euromaidan 2013-2014".  Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Oh, please.  Some of us are new to Python, in fact programming.  I'm a lit and gender studies student taking a mandatory introducion to programming class.  Final grade project is to write script for detecting suggestions per Chicago manual.

Comment: @SerhiiVovk We must still attempt to maintain the standards and conventions of SO though, no? It's really nothing personal. Good luck with your final project :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
import re

with open("find_these.txt") as f:
    regexes = [x.strip() for x in f]

with open("text.txt") as f:
    text = [x.strip() for x in f]
print text

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for pattern in regexes:
        for index, line in enumerate(text):
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                f.write("%s ---> %s ---> %s\n" %(pattern, index+1, line))
```

Note that this may not be the most efficient way to do this, but it should solve your problem for a comparatively small data set.

Comment: MohitC, works brilliant, thank you.  Anyway to enhance it to show (1) multiple instances of find, (2) showing column (character in the line) of find?  Thank you again.

Comment: Would leave that to you. You can easily find column matching by finding index of the character matched in the line.

Comment: Would like to know why there is negative vote on this. This is what they say about stackoverflow these days.

Comment: Sorry MohitC, somebody gave negative rating. Pls see above.  Your help appreciate much. I'm humanities major worked hard to learn good programming for class.  I spent all day on YouTube tutorials and gave up and asked for help here.

Comment: @SerhiiVovk sorry we can not code your entire assignment for you. Please ask specific questions with different issues you face. You can ask that in a different question, but you have to research a little first and post your most promising attempts of coding.

Comment: Thank you.  The assignment is a lot more than this and I am fitting your bit into a larger script.

Comment: A few tips: `readlines()` reads the entire file into memory at once. Since you're iterating over each line anyway, you can replace `regexes = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]` with `regexes = [x.strip() for x in f]`. You used a context manager for the first two files, which is good, but not the third. Why is that? Finally, `%` formatting is rather old at this point, it's probably better to use f-strings, or at least `.format()`.

Comment: I just noticed: The order of the loops is problematic, there will almost certainly be an error on the second iteration of the `for pattern in regexes` loop.

Answer (score -4):

I believe the existing answer will lead to some issues, due to the order of the loops, so I thought I would write up a quick solution.

---

**Important things to note:**

- Reading the patterns from a file like this could lead to some problems, as it stands I'm not entirely confident. It is quite late though, I will update this tomorrow once I've had some sleep.
- This solution keeps all the patterns in memory throughout the entire program, which could be an issue depending on the number of patterns.

`find_these.txt`:

```
hello
hi\n
\bbye\b
```

`text.txt`:

```
Hello there. Goodbye.
A line. Bye line! Another line
which ends here. Hi
```

Code:

```py
import csv
import re

with open("../resources/find_these.txt") as patt_file:
    re_patts = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in patt_file]

out_headers = ["line_num", "line_text", "patt", "match_start", "match_end"]

with open("../resources/text.txt") as corp_file, open("../out/output.txt", "w", newline="") as out_file:
    out_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    out_writer.writerow(out_headers)

    for line_num, corp_line in enumerate(corp_file, start=1):
        for curr_patt in re_patts:
            for curr_match in re.finditer(curr_patt, corp_line, re.IGNORECASE):
                out_writer.writerow((line_num, corp_line, curr_patt, curr_match.start(), curr_match.end()))
```

`output.txt`:

```
line_num,line_text,patt,match_start,match_end
1,"Hello there. Goodbye.
",hello,0,5
2,"A line. Bye line! Another line
",\bbye\b,8,11
3,"which ends here. Hi
",hi\n,17,20
```

Let me know if anything isn't clear :)